# SQL Server pivot table as dynamic SQL

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have the code below sitting in a stored procedure (SQL Server 2008). The code has been placed in a string in order to allow one of the parameters to have more than one value. The problem I have is when I test the SQL in SQL Server Management Studio it says that my string is not a valid identifier, and points to the line which I have put double ** around.

I cannot see what I have done wrong, and would like to know whether I have either missed something or ask whether this sort of query can be executed a dynamically. If the latter is not possible, then how does one pass a number of parameters to a query of this sort?

Thanks

```
DECLARE @SQL AS VARCHAR(MAX)

SELECT @SQL = 'select Production_Site, [Target],[Action],[Fail]'
SELECT @SQL = @SQL + ' from'
SELECT @SQL = @SQL + ' ('
SELECT @SQL = @SQL + ' select Production_Site, value, Period, YEAR, week'
SELECT @SQL = @SQL + ' from t_Pqe_Grocery'
SELECT @SQL = @SQL + ' unpivot ('
SELECT @SQL = @SQL + ' value'
SELECT @SQL = @SQL + ' for col in (Grocery_Packaging_And_Coding, Grocery_Measurable,'
SELECT @SQL = @SQL + ' Grocery_Appearance, Grocery_Aroma,'
**SELECT @SQL = @SQL + ' Grocery_Flavour, Grocery_Texture)) unp'**
SELECT @SQL = @SQL + ' ) src '
SELECT @SQL = @SQL + ' pivot '
SELECT @SQL = @SQL + ' ('
SELECT @SQL = @SQL + ' count(value)'
SELECT @SQL = @SQL + ' for value in ([Target], [Action], [Fail])'
SELECT @SQL = @SQL + ' ) piv'
SELECT @SQL = @SQL + ' where Production_Site IN (' + @Site + ') AND YEAR = ' + 
                     CONVERT(varchar(50), CONVERT(BIGINT, @Year)) + ' AND Period = ' + 
                     CONVERT(varchar(50), CONVERT(BIGINT, @Period)) + ' and Week = ' +   
                     CONVERT(varchar(50), CONVERT(BIGINT, @Week)) 
EXECUTE @SQL
```

Comment: Did you read my post? I said I have highlighted the row which I feel is the problem with double **. Please read the post before commenting

Comment: @Andy5 what is the value of `@SQL` when you `print @SQL`? what is the full query before you `execute`?

Comment: I see the whole query, plus the parameters I have passed in

Comment: Yeah. Select @SQL and paste it here. You can even try to execute it and check errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `EXECUTE @SQL` to `EXECUTE (@SQL)`.  I believe it's the syntax problem.

Try pasting this into SSMS and running it, it runs without quotes issue:

```
DECLARE @Site VARCHAR(1000) = '''Avonmouth'',''Lifton'''
DECLARE @Year VARCHAR(50) = '12'
DECLARE @Period VARCHAR(50) = '10'
DECLARE @Week VARCHAR(50) ='41'

DECLARE @SQL AS VARCHAR(MAX)

SELECT @SQL = 'select Production_Site, [Target],[Action],[Fail]'
SELECT @SQL = @SQL + ' from'
SELECT @SQL = @SQL + ' ('
SELECT @SQL = @SQL + ' select Production_Site, value, Period, YEAR, week'
SELECT @SQL = @SQL + ' from t_Pqe_Grocery'
SELECT @SQL = @SQL + ' unpivot ('
SELECT @SQL = @SQL + ' value'
SELECT @SQL = @SQL + ' for col in (Grocery_Packaging_And_Coding, Grocery_Measurable,'
SELECT @SQL = @SQL + ' Grocery_Appearance, Grocery_Aroma,'
SELECT @SQL = @SQL + ' Grocery_Flavour, Grocery_Texture)) unp'
SELECT @SQL = @SQL + ' ) src '
SELECT @SQL = @SQL + ' pivot '
SELECT @SQL = @SQL + ' ('
SELECT @SQL = @SQL + ' count(value)'
SELECT @SQL = @SQL + ' for value in ([Target], [Action], [Fail])'
SELECT @SQL = @SQL + ' ) piv'
SELECT @SQL = @SQL + ' where Production_Site IN (' + @Site + ') AND YEAR = ' + 
                     CONVERT(varchar(50), CONVERT(BIGINT, @Year)) + ' AND Period = ' + 
                     CONVERT(varchar(50), CONVERT(BIGINT, @Period)) + ' and Week = ' +   
                     CONVERT(varchar(50), CONVERT(BIGINT, @Week)) 
PRINT @SQL
EXECUTE (@SQL)
```

Comment: Hi I have just noticed that, but it is failing because when I put just one value or more values it says invalid column name on the parameter

Comment: I think it's the syntax error inside the dynamic SQL. Try to debug it by using `PRINT @SQL` just before `EXECUTE (@SQL)` and the actual text will be printed in 'Messages' window. Copy-paste this text and run it, then you'll see the line where the actual error is...

Comment: What is happening is that the parameter value that is being passed to to the in clause has no quotes round it. I have tried putting more single quotes in the sql string, but it complained even more. How do you get round this

Comment: How do you construct `@Site` variable's contents? If you want to insert single quotes in string, you have to use two single quotes, example: `SELECT 'My name is ''Joe'''` will produce string with single quotes around 'Joe'.

Comment: It is IN ('' + variable_name + ''), but this returns the variable name

Comment: Ok, it worked with one parameter being '''+variable parameter+''', but if tried to put more than one in it says too many parameters

Comment: Can you post the actual content of the `@SQL` as it is being passed to `EXECUTE (@SQL)`? You can obtain it by using `PRINT @SQL` before the call to the `EXECUTE (@SQL)`...

Comment: select Production_Site, [Target],[Action],[Fail] from ( select Production_Site, value, Period, YEAR, week from t_Pqe_Grocery unpivot ( value for col in (Grocery_Packaging_And_Coding, Grocery_Measurable, Grocery_Appearance, Grocery_Aroma, Grocery_Flavour, Grocery_Texture)) unp ) src pivot ( count(value) for value in ([Target], [Action], [Fail]) ) piv where Production_Site IN ('+ @Site + ' ) AND YEAR=12 AND Period=10 and Week=41

Comment: OK, can you post how you created the contents of the `@Site` variable? How does `@Site` gets populated? Problem is with that variable.

Comment: At the moment I am testing in SQL Management Studio, but the intention is have this variable populated via a Listbox control where a user can make as many selections as they like

Comment: in Management Studio I am doing execute sp_proc @Site="'Avonmouth','Lifton'", @Year='12', @Period='10',@Week='41'

Comment: Try it like this: `@Site = '''Avonmouth'',''Lifton'''` - I believe this is the correct syntax...

Comment: The output of `PRINT` should be: `...piv where Production_Site IN ('Avonmouth','Lifton') AND YEAR=12 AND Period=10 and Week=41`

Comment: Make sure that you have triple single quote around `@Site` when you concatenate it's contents, check that your code looks like this: `SELECT @SQL = @SQL + ' where Production_Site IN (''' + @Site + ''') AND YEAR...`

Comment: This is what I am doing and seeing: execute usp_Aggregate_Grocery_Site_TAF_TEST @Site ='''Avonmouth'',''Lifton''', @Year='12', @Period='10',@Week='41'
select Production_Site, [Target],[Action],[Fail] from ( select Production_Site, value, Period, YEAR, week from t_Pqe_Grocery unpivot ( value for col in (Grocery_Packaging_And_Coding, Grocery_Measurable, Grocery_Appearance, Grocery_Aroma, Grocery_Flavour, Grocery_Texture)) unp ) src pivot ( count(value) for value in ([Target], [Action], [Fail]) ) piv where Production_Site IN ('+ variable_name_here + ' ) AND YEAR=12 AND Period=10 and Week=41

Comment: I updated my answer, try running it as query in SSMS, quotes problem is resolved...

Comment: How do I format the input parameters to pass the values into the stored procedure?

Answer (score 0):

I am going to guess that you do not have enough single quotes around the `@site` parameter than you are passing in.  Add the following:

```
Production_Site IN (''' + @Site + ''')
```

If `@site` is a string value, then you need to have single quotes around it. Your current query is missing them.

So your final query is:

```
DECLARE @SQL AS VARCHAR(MAX)

SELECT @SQL = 'select Production_Site, [Target],[Action],[Fail]'
SELECT @SQL = @SQL + ' from'
SELECT @SQL = @SQL + ' ('
SELECT @SQL = @SQL + ' select Production_Site, value, Period, YEAR, week'
SELECT @SQL = @SQL + ' from t_Pqe_Grocery'
SELECT @SQL = @SQL + ' unpivot ('
SELECT @SQL = @SQL + ' value'
SELECT @SQL = @SQL + ' for col in (Grocery_Packaging_And_Coding, Grocery_Measurable,'
SELECT @SQL = @SQL + ' Grocery_Appearance, Grocery_Aroma,'
SELECT @SQL = @SQL + ' Grocery_Flavour, Grocery_Texture)) unp'
SELECT @SQL = @SQL + ' ) src '
SELECT @SQL = @SQL + ' pivot '
SELECT @SQL = @SQL + ' ('
SELECT @SQL = @SQL + ' count(value)'
SELECT @SQL = @SQL + ' for value in ([Target], [Action], [Fail])'
SELECT @SQL = @SQL + ' ) piv'
SELECT @SQL = @SQL + ' where Production_Site IN (''' + @Site + ''') AND YEAR = ' + 
                     CONVERT(varchar(50), CONVERT(BIGINT, @Year)) + ' AND Period = ' + 
                     CONVERT(varchar(50), CONVERT(BIGINT, @Period)) + ' and Week = ' +   
                     CONVERT(varchar(50), CONVERT(BIGINT, @Week)) 

EXECUTE (@SQL)
```